# setState error for onclick in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm get this error
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to componentWillMount 
for

```
<a key={brand} onClick={this.someFn(Brands[brand])}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <a key={brand} onClick={() => this.someFn(Brands[brand])}>
```

call it with an arrow function

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise against mutating the state inside `render()` methods. In fact it is strongly suggested by the maintainers of React, to keep the `render()` method as a pure function.

If you want to change the state between different components, for example if you have a sidebar, the most robust solution is to use `Redux` or an equivalent application state library.

Comment: I can't use redux or another state library. I think I'll use function to pass icon from the child component to the parent component without any state modification